# Including libfcgi files when installing QGIS on SUSE Linux

Tags: qgis, installation, linux

I'm using SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 11 SP2. When I try to install QGIS from YAST, it seems that the package "libfcgi.so.0" and "libfcgi.so.1" are missing.

Where can I get those files?

Answer (score 1):

In openSUSE these packages are provided by FastCGI. You can install it for SUSE SLE-11 SP2 [from here](http://software.opensuse.org/package/FastCGI).